# Diagonal set of the cross product of two circles

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the set of the cross product of two circles is a torus , but what about the diagonal set , I have an idea about it but I just want to make sure because the book I am using has no solution manual , thanks , and please give links so I can visualize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal set is simply a circle which make both a turn of the little circle and the big circle of the torus.